# How to check for repeating data coming from server in for loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have sorted data coming from the server. It's invoked from an infinite scroll.

I want to push data that is not a repeat to a client-side array. If duplication starts, I want to return and end infinite scroll.

```
$scope.collections = [];

$scope.isBusy = false;

$scope.queryObject = {
    size: 12,
    sorter: 'timestamp',
    sort: {
      timestamp: -1
    },
    skip: 0
  }

$scope.loadMore = function() {
    if ($scope.isBusy == true) {
      return;
    }

    $scope.isBusy = true;

    Collect.all($scope.queryObject).then(function(res) {


      for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.collections.length && res.data) {
          for (var j = res.data.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if ($scope.collections[0]._id == res.data[j]._id) {
              console.log('match', res.data[j])
              return;
            }
          }
          $scope.collections.push(res.data[i])
        }
        else{
        $scope.collections.push(res.data[i])
        }
      }

      $scope.queryObject.skip += 12;
      $scope.isBusy = false;
    });
  };
```

---

My attempt here is to check res.data in reverse order against the first index of the collections array. If there is a repeat, to then end the infinite scroll / loadMore().

I keep getting res.data._id is not defined, but if I remove it and just check collections[0] vs res.data[j] it shows a match immediately, and the console.log shows res.data[j] with a defined ._id .

I'm sure there something very basic I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do this.

```
var dummyArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
    if(dummyArray.indexOf(res.data[i]._id === -1) {
       $scope.collections.push(res.data[i]);
       dummyArray.push(res.data[i]._id);
    } 
    else {
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting repeats. I think my initial logic is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.collections.length && res.data) {
          for (var j = res.data.length; j >= 0; j--) {  //modify this line to j = res.data.length - 1;
            if ($scope.collections[0]._id == res.data[j]._id) {
              console.log('match', res.data[j])
              return;
            }
          }
          $scope.collections.push(res.data[i])
        }
        else{
        $scope.collections.push(res.data[i])
        }
      }
```

Comment: thanks for catching that error. Still getting duplicated data, though.

Comment: `if ($scope.collections.length && res.data) {` what did you try to check actually by this line? I guess if i understand your approach clearly then i may be able to help you.